# HTML парсер для ios

Tags: xcode, парсер, ios, html

Подскажите, пытаюсь использовать [этот парсер](https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser),  но, как вы сами понимаете, безуспешно.

```
Open Your project in XCode and drag and drop all .h & .m Files into an appropriate folder
    In the project settings add "/usr/include/libxml2" to the "header search paths" field
    Ctrl Click the Frameworks group choose Add -> Existing Frameworks and from the list choose libxml2.dylib
```

Эти 3 пункта выполнил, но как только пытаюсь вставить пример из гитхаба в ViewController.m (сюда же надо вставлять?), вылетает куча ошибок, например  не так поставлен знак `;` в строке `NSError *error = nil;` и т.д.

Направьте, скажите, куда точно нужно вставлять пример, чтобы он заработал (имею в виду файл).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios